# How can you delete a PlatformEventChannelMember record via the REST api?

Tags: rest-api, delete, change-data-capture

I am trying to configure Change Data Capture for the `ChangeEvents` channel via the REST API as you can in Setup Change Data Capture when using the Salesforce UI.

I am able to add records of `PlatformEventChannelMember` via a REST `POST` call:
`/services/data/v50.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember`.  The current documentation is clear on the payload required.

The documentation indicates that REST `DELETE` is available for `PlatformEventChannelMember`, but I haven't had success using it.  I couldn't find an example or documentation for the payload.  I made an attempt using the same payload as had succeeded for `POST`.  This results in a `405` error. `HTTP Method 'DELETE' not allowed`. `DELETE` is documented as available for the endpoint.

I also attempted to use `DELETE` with both the `/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/{{ObjectId}}` and `/services/data/v50.0/tooling/sobjects/{{ObjectId}}` REST paths unsuccessfully.  Though the object id is easily queried via SOQL using the tooling API.  Both return a `404` `The requested resource does not exist` error.  The provided `{{ObjectId}}` was returned by both the successful `POST` on `PlatformEventChannelMember`, and by a tooling API Soql query:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM PlatformEventChannelMember WHERE SelectedEntity = 'DeleteableGrommet__c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce APIs aren't very self-consistent, and the documentation is incomplete, but just by trial and error, I found this to work flawlessly:

`DELETE` on `/services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember/{{ObjectId}}`